# Max value's index in array with uniform distribution when there are several max values, and number of max values is known

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

This is an interview question I saw without a good solution.
The first part of the question was:
Given a vector of integers, find the index of the maximum value. However, if there are multiple maximum values - you want that every index of a max value will have an equal probability to be chosen.

For example: if we have the vector `(0,1,2,2,2,2)` , then index 2 has probability of 0.25 to be chosen (and the same for indexes 3,4,5).

You can solve it in C++ like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int getIndex(const vector<int>& numbers) {
  int maxNum = numeric_limits<int>::min();
  size_t idx = -1;
  size_t maxNumCtr = 0;

  for(size_t i = 0; i<numbers.size(); ++i) {
    int num = numbers[i];
    if(num > maxNum) {
      idx = i;
      maxNum = num;
      maxNumCtr = 1;
    } else if (num == maxNum) {
      maxNumCtr ++;
      idx = ((rand() % maxNumCtr) == 0) ? i : idx; 
    }
  }
  return idx;
}
```

The second part was:
Now you have an extra parameter for the function which indicates the number of occurances of the max value in the vector. Try to improve the run time of the algorithm you wrote.

My idea is that you can caculate `rand()` just one time in the beginning of the function to find a uniformly distributed max index , and use some counter variable for knowing when you get the correct max index in the loop. But this does not improve the run time since `rand` runs in `O(1)`.

Any better idea?

Comment: Well the first algorithm is already `O(n)` and you can't go lower since you need to read every element, so I'd say you can't improve the run-time complexity of the algorithm (which I assume is what "the run time" means here).

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- *This is an interview question* -- Well, if it's a C++ programming position, any company worth their salt would reject this.

Answer (score 0):

Just because something has the same big-O complexity doesn't mean it has the same runtime. The interview is asking for a change in the constant factor, not a complexity improvement.

Here's how I'd do it without the count

```
// Undefined if first == last
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename URBG>
int getIndex(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, URBG&& gen)
{
    int max = *std::max_element(first, last);
    std::vector<double> weights;
    std::transform(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::back_inserter(weights), [max](int i){ return i == max; });
    // or auto weights = numbers | ranges::view::transform([max](int i){ return i == max; });

    std::discrete_distribution<int> dis(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    return dis(gen);
}
```

That has 2 passes over the data, and constructs one `std::discrete_distribution` of the same size

If you instead already had a count of how many to pick from, you could do it in one pass and use a `std::uniform_int_distribution`

```
// Undefined if first == last
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename URBG>
int getIndex(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, size_t max_count, URBG&& gen)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, max_count);
    std::size_t nth = dis(gen);

    ForwardIterator best = first;
    std::size_t nth_best = nth;

    for (ForwardIterator it = first; it != last; ++it)
    {
        if (*best < *it)
        {
            // new max
            best = it;
            nth_best = nth;
        }
        else if (*it < *best) {} // nothing
        else if ((--nth_best) == 0) 
        {
            // found nth of this value
            best = it;
        }
    }

    return std::distance(first, best);
}
```

Comment: OP's algorithm for the first question (without the count) already does it in one pass. I don't think you would be improving the run-time for the second question if you started with that.

Comment: @Nelfeal I'm not sure OP's algorithm is uniformly picking between indexes.

Comment: It is (as far as `rand` goes). With a single element, the probability of picking it is `1`. When a second element is added, the probability of picking that new one is `1/2`, so it's still uniform. When a third is added, the probability of picking this one is `1/3`, so the probability of staying with one of the previous two is `2/3`, and so each has an overall probability of being picked of `1/2 * 2/3 = 1/3`. So it's still uniform. And so on.

Comment: @Nelfeal Ah, ok. Well let's just assume that `rand()` is and "expensive O(1)" call. The count lets you call it once